# How to read a list in a text file in python

Tags: python, list, text

I have this list

```
l1=[[[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7]],[8,9,10],[11,12,13,14]]
```

and I save this list in a text file

```
with open('l1.txt', 'w') as f1:
      f1.write(str(l1))
```

Now I have a text file with the list.
How can I read this list in python?
I tried with

```
list1= open("l1.txt", "r")
list2= list1.read()
l1= list2.strip('][').split(', ')
```

With this I have

```
l1=['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14']
```

but this isn't the list I have at the beginning

Comment: `l1=[[[0,1,2,3,4][5,6,7]][8,9,10][11,12,13,14]]` is not correct python as `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`, please fix that

Comment: Sorry, I will fix it right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Cardstdani mentioned, you can try to use `eval`. However, I suggest avoiding eval in all but the rarest of cases.

I would suggest serialising and deserialising it in some nice, way, such as using JSON:

Save:

```py
import json

l1=[[[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7]],[8,9,10],[11,12,13,14]]

with open("l1.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(l1, f)
```

Load:

```py
import json

with open("l1.json") as f:
    l1 = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Serialization is the way to go for what you're wanting to do. There are different libraries for this, but `json` would be ideal in this case since you're not using any custom classes.

```
import json

l1=[[[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7]],[8,9,10],[11,12,13,14]]

with open('l1.txt', 'w') as f1:
    json.dump(l1, f1)

with open('l1.txt', 'w') as f2:
    l2 = json.load(f2)

print(l1 == l2)
# True
```

As a side note for the other answer, while `eval` would work, it's extremely unsafe (someone could easily write malicious code in your text file), and I'd recommend you to forget about it until you become a lot more proficient at coding.

Answer (score 1):

You might use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), it is safer than `eval` (see docs), in this case

```
import ast
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]] # original list
s = str(x) # string representation
x2 = ast.literal_eval(s) # list built from representation
print(x == x2) # True
```

Note: for brevity I do not include writing/reading to files, which can be done as for any normal text file

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `eval()` function to read explicitly from a text file and then convert to a valid Python multi-dimensional list:

```
l1 = eval("[[[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7]],[8,9,10],[11,12,13,14]]")
print(l1)

#In your case
list1= open("l1.txt", "r")
list2= list1.read()
l1= eval(list2)
```

*Output:**

```
[[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]], [8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14]]
```